# What Impact on subdomain to change the NS server record

Tags: web-hosting, subdomain, cpanel, nameserver, dns-servers

I want to change my hosting services to another service provider.
What will be the impact on subdomains if I change the new hosting NS record on domain registrar.

Currently I am using the multiple subdomains on my old web hosting and redirecting to another server but the same subdomains I have created on the new hosting server and redirect on the same IP address that I used on the old hosting server.

After changing the NS record the subdomain will be working fine without any down time?

For Example:
Domain registrar: godaddy

For Website/Domain name: test.com  IP address: 192.168.0.1

Subdomain A records: live.test.com  IP address:10.10.10.1

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, technically the domain registrar is irrelevant. What counts here are what are the current and new DNS providers. Granted, the registrar can be a DNS provider too, but that remains a separate job. You change NS records through the registrar that will push them to the registry. You change zone content at the current DNS provider.

Answer (score 2):

Before you change the nameservers;

At the new host, make sure your sub-domains are set up in DNS *and* ensure you have the files migrated properly to the correct directories.  Also set up your redirects.

If you do all this, there should not be any impact on the sub-domains.